# How to format ruby date like 16d 2h 50m?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to format a ruby date like this:

```
16d 2h 50m
```

How can I do this?

Also, what is that helper that gives you a date like '3 minutes ago'?

Comment: the helper is `time_ago_in_words` (from now) or `distance_of_time_in_words` (accepting 2 time arguments)

Answer (score 3):

> t = Time.now
>
> t.strftime("%dd %Hh %Mm")

You could have used Date object like Date.today as well instead of Time, but that would return only day with 0 for hours and minutes.

For second one:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words

Comment: I actually have the time coming from a hash object like my_hash["current_time"]   and it says strftime is undefined.

Comment: What is the object in Hash. String? Can you post an example of format?

Comment: Looking at the question it seems it would be an interval, like `time1 - time2`